# Why does my Nikon camera get stuck when using A,M or S mode?

Tags: nikon, troubleshooting, camera-settings, shutter-release

I own a Nikon D5200 and I am a beginner. I've been watching videos on Youtube and exploring the ways to use it. When I use `A`, `M` or `S` mode, after pressing the shutter button, the camera hangs. I have to switch it off and on again and again. Are there any technical issues with the camera, or is my usage wrong?

Comment: When you switch it off and back on is the picture you took saved to the card? It sounds like you may have *Shutter Delay* enabled, which means the shutter press raises the mirror (and blocks the viewfinder) for 2 seconds before the photo is actually taken.

Comment: Seems you have a very low (even bulb mode) in M, S mode. And very dark object so the time is slow, too. What value of shutter speed is displayed?

Answer (score 1):

Switch the camera to S and take a picture, record the time it takes to take a picture with a stopwatch. If it is anything over 30 seconds then you have a fault with the camera because bulb mode requires a cable release for anything over that speed.

If you find that the time delay is 30 seconds then you can adjust the shutter speed to a shorter time, for 30 seconds a 30" will be displayed on the info window.

If you use your camera in A mode then it will adjust the shutter speed. If you are testing it in dark conditions than you will have a long shutter delay so go outside and in the daylight, put it in A and see how long it takes, it should not that long.

Then providing these conditions are true it means your camera is OK and that you need to read the manual for information on how to use those modes.